# What is this grammar structure, adding a noun after the verb "stand"

Tags: grammar

I have been reading *The Dark Elf trilogy* and one sentence got my attention, and I don't know what grammar structure is behind the sentence which justifies its grammatical correctness.

The sentence is:

> "Where, in ages past, there had been an empty cavern of roughly shaped stalactites and stalagmites now **stands artistry**."

I do understand the meaning of "stands artistry" means the cavern now looks good, but I can't search other similar usage of adding a noun after the verb "stand".

Comment: Have you researched what kind of verb *stand* is with this meaning?

Comment: I do have researched for different explanation of the verb "stand" to justify this. I also find the usage of "stand empty" quite similar to this one but again, empty is adjective. I still don't understand how "stands artistry" is correct in the novel. If it follows the rule of "stand empty", wouldn't it be "stand artistically"?

Comment: @Danny: I think what's causing the confusion here is mistaking **stands** for a transitive verb, when in fact it is used intransitively here (a linking verb, perhaps). And the meaning is: _to be placed or situated._ _The American Heritage Dictionary_ provides this usage of **stand** under the intransitive heading: _The building stands at the corner_, which could be rephrased as: _At the corner stands the building._ This is similar to your sentence [Verb+NP].

Comment: @user405662. Thank you for providing an example.

Comment: Yes: "stands" here takes a predicative complement, not a direct object.

Comment: Where once was farmland, now stands my house. My grandmother in London might have said this around 1890.

Comment: ... Michael gives a clearer example of the structure, which is subject-final.  << My house stands on that hill. >> is the typical S-Vint-Comp loc structure; << On that hill stands my house >> is the inverted-for-literary-effect C-V-S structure.

Comment: @user405662 ... Convert your comment to an answer

Comment: @BillJ Well, a locative complement!

Comment: @GEdgar... Done. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think what's causing the confusion here is mistaking **stands** for a transitive verb, when in fact it is used intransitively here (a linking verb, perhaps). And the meaning is: *to be placed or situated.* *The American Heritage Dictionary* provides this usage of **stand** under the intransitive heading: *The building stands at the corner*, which could be rephrased as: *At the corner stands the building.* This is similar to your sentence [Verb+NP].

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Araucaria for suggesting a useful edit to the answer. Constructions such as this are examples of S-V inversion (precisely, *locative inversion* in this case.)

Per Wikipedia, *An adjunct phrase is switched from its default postverbal position to a position preceding the verb, which causes the subject and the finite verb to invert. The fronted expression that evokes locative inversion is an adjunct of location.*

Comment: +1 You could add that this is a case of subject dependent inversion (sometimes called 'locative inversion'. If the feeling takes you :)

Comment: Or close-vote as a duplicate.